# How to extract particular part of an url in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I want to extract particular part of an url and manupulate it using BeanShell PreProcessor in Jmeter.

can anyone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a Regular Expression Extractor post-processor element as a child of the sampler from which you are going to extract the URL and in "Field to check" check the "URL". [Here](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) you can find more info about regular expression extractor and how to use it. And from [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) you can learn more about referencing functions and variables in JMeter.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: No problem. If you still can't make what you need lemme know what part of it bothers you.

Comment: "   &when=29-05-2016&until=&flexibility=true&flexibleDays=3&noOfAdults=2&noOfSeniors=0&noOfChildren=2&childrenAge=2%204&duration=7114&    " in this i want to extact  2%204   and i want replace 0 with C

Comment: i used regular expression and **checked url**.it works .thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in many ways .

1. regular expression extractor and select which part you want to extract and do the processor on it [in your case select the url] store it as a variable
2. add a post processor select language of your choice ,[plugin must be applied here]

i have done a sample here in groovy since groovy has a build in url library to access parts of the url

```
log.info vars.get("iurl")
input =vars.get("iurl")
URI ulrString = new URI(input[0])
vars.put("gHost",ulrString.getHost().toString())
vars.put("gPort",ulrString.getPort().toString())
vars.put("gPathUrl",ulrString.getPath().toString())
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what part you need and what you can do with it approaches might differ, here is one of them:

In [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) you have `sampler` pre-defined variable which stands for parent Sampler instance. In case of [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) it is [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html) class. So you can use `sampler.getUrl()` method to get the whole URL, it will return [java.net.URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) instance so you will be able to use URL class methods to work with it like:

```
URL url = sampler.getUrl();

String protocol = url.getProtocol();
String host = url.getHost();
String path = url.getPath();

log.info("URL: " + url.toString());
log.info("Protocol: " + protocol);
log.info("Host: " + host);
log.info("Path: " + path);
```

Demo:

[image: Beanshell URL]

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on using JMeter and Java APIs from Beanshell test elements.

Comment: hey .. thanks..its giving me clear idea.

Comment: " &when=29-05-2016&until=&flexibility=true&flexibleDays=3&noOfAdults=2&noOfSeniors‌​=0&noOfChildren=2&childrenAge=2%204&duration=7114& " in this i want to extact 2%204 and i want replace 0 with C